# How to Bind to CaretIndex aka curser position of an Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, textbox

Hi I'm trying to bind to the `TextBox.CaretIndex` property which isn't a `DependencyProperty`, so I created a `Behavior`, but it doesn't work as expected.

**Expectation (when focused)**

- default = 0
- if I change the value in my **view** it should change the value in my **viewmodel**
- if I change the value in my **viewmodel** it should change the value in my **view**

**Current behavior**

- viewmodel value gets called ones when the window opens

**Code-behind**

```
public class TextBoxBehavior : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CursorPositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CursorPosition",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(TextBoxBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                default(int),
                new PropertyChangedCallback(CursorPositionChanged)));

    public static void SetCursorPosition(DependencyObject dependencyObject, int i)
    {
        // breakpoint get never called
        dependencyObject.SetValue(CursorPositionProperty, i); 
    }

    public static int GetCursorPosition(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        // breakpoint get never called
        return (int)dependencyObject.GetValue(CursorPositionProperty);
    }

    private static void CursorPositionChanged(
        DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // breakpoint get never called
        //var textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        //if (textBox == null) return;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextTemplate,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         local:TextBoxBehavior.CursorPosition="{Binding CursorPosition}"/>
```

**Further Information**

I think there is something really wrong here because I need to derive it from `DependencyObject` which was never needed before, because `CursorPositionProperty` is already a `DependencyProperty`, so this should be enough. I also think I need to use some events in my `Behavior` to set my `CursorPositionProperty` correctly, but I don't know which.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After fighting with my Behavior i can present you a **99%** working solution

**Behavior**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfMVVMTextBoxCursorPosition
{
    public class TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior : DependencyObject
    {
        public static void SetCursorPosition(DependencyObject dependencyObject, int i)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(CursorPositionProperty, i);
        }

        public static int GetCursorPosition(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            return (int)dependencyObject.GetValue(CursorPositionProperty);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CursorPositionProperty =
                                           DependencyProperty.Register("CursorPosition"
                                                                       , typeof(int)
                                                                       , typeof(TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior)
                                                                       , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int))
                                                                       {
                                                                           BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
                                                                           ,DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                                                                       }
                                                                       );

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackCaretIndexProperty =
                                                    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                        "TrackCaretIndex",
                                                        typeof(bool),
                                                        typeof(TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior),
                                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(false
                                                                                , OnTrackCaretIndex));

        public static void SetTrackCaretIndex(DependencyObject dependencyObject, bool i)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(TrackCaretIndexProperty, i);
        }

        public static bool GetTrackCaretIndex(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            return (bool)dependencyObject.GetValue(TrackCaretIndexProperty);
        }

        private static void OnTrackCaretIndex(DependencyObject dependency, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textbox = dependency as TextBox;

            if (textbox == null)
                return;
            bool oldValue = (bool)e.OldValue;
            bool newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

            if (!oldValue && newValue) // If changed from false to true
            {
                textbox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
            }
            else if (oldValue && !newValue) // If changed from true to false
            {
                textbox.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
            }
        }

        private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textbox = sender as TextBox;

            if (textbox != null)
                SetCursorPosition(textbox, textbox.CaretIndex); // dies line does nothing
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
    <TextBox Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Name="TestTextBox"
             Text="{Binding MyText}"
             vm:TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior.TrackCaretIndex="True"
             vm:TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior.CursorPosition="{Binding CursorPosition,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding CursorPosition}"/>
```

there is just on thing i don't know why it doesn't work => `BindsTwoWayByDefault = true`. it has no effect on the binding as far as i can tell you because of this i need to set the binding mode explicit in XAML

Comment: **public static int GetTrackCaretIndex(DependencyObject dependencyObject)** should return **bool** as it is a boolean property. + **return (bool) dependencyObject.GetValue(TrackCaretIndexProperty);** Otherwise you get a _"Input string was not in a correct format."_ XAML-error.

Comment: CursorPosition also needs to use RegisterAttached

Comment: This sets the videmodel property on selection change perfectly, but when I change the viewmodel property from code, it does not change the caretindex on UI. Anything missing?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem, and the easiest solution for me was to inherit from TextBox and add a DependencyProperty. So it looks like this:

```
namespace UI.Controls
{
    public class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CaretPositionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CaretPosition", typeof(int), typeof(MyTextBox),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnCaretPositionChanged));

        public int CaretPosition
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(CaretPositionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CaretPositionProperty, value); }
        }

        public MyTextBox()
        {
            SelectionChanged += (s, e) => CaretPosition = CaretIndex;
        }

        private static void OnCaretPositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as MyTextBox).CaretIndex = (int)e.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

... and in my XAML:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:IU.Controls"
...
<controls:MyTextBox CaretPosition="{Binding CaretPosition}"/>
```

... and CaretPosition property in the View Model of course. If you're not going to bind your View Model to other text-editing controls, this may be sufficient, if yes - you'll probably need another solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution from WiiMaxx has the following problems for me:

1. The caret index in the text box is not changed when the view model property is changed from the code.
   This was also mentioned by Tejas Vaishnav in his comment to the solution.
2. `BindsTwoWayByDefault = true` does not work.
3. He stated that it is strange that he needs to inherit from `DependencyObject`.
4. The TrackCaretIndex property is only used for initialisation and it felt kind of unnecessary.

Here is my solution which solves those problems:

**Behavior**

```
public static class TextBoxAssist
{

    // This strange default value is on purpose it makes the initialization problem very unlikely.
    // If the default value matches the default value of the property in the ViewModel,
    // the propertyChangedCallback of the FrameworkPropertyMetadata is initially not called
    // and if the property in the ViewModel is not changed it will never be called.
    private const int CaretIndexPropertyDefault = -485609317;

    public static void SetCaretIndex(DependencyObject dependencyObject, int i)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(CaretIndexProperty, i);
    }

    public static int GetCaretIndex(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (int)dependencyObject.GetValue(CaretIndexProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaretIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "CaretIndex",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(TextBoxAssist),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                CaretIndexPropertyDefault,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                CaretIndexChanged));

    private static void CaretIndexChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (dependencyObject is not TextBox textBox || eventArgs.OldValue is not int oldValue || eventArgs.NewValue is not int newValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (oldValue == CaretIndexPropertyDefault && newValue != CaretIndexPropertyDefault)
        {
            textBox.SelectionChanged += SelectionChangedForCaretIndex;
        }
        else if (oldValue != CaretIndexPropertyDefault && newValue == CaretIndexPropertyDefault)
        {
            textBox.SelectionChanged -= SelectionChangedForCaretIndex;
        }

        if (newValue != textBox.CaretIndex)
        {
            textBox.CaretIndex = newValue;
        }
    }

    private static void SelectionChangedForCaretIndex(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox)
        {
            SetCaretIndex(textBox, textBox.CaretIndex);
        }
    }

}
```

**XAML**

```
    <TextBox Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Name="TestTextBox"
             Text="{Binding MyText}"
             viewModels:TextBoxAssist.CaretIndex="{Binding CaretIndex}"/>
```

Some clarifications for the differences:

- View model property changes work now because the caret index on the `TextBox` is set at the end of `CaretIndexChanged`.
- The `BindsTwoWayByDefault` was fixed by using the according `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` constructor parameter.
- Inheriting from `DependencyObject` was only necessary because `DependencyProperty.Register` was used instead of `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`.
- Without the TrackCaretIndex property I had the problem that the `propertyChangedCallback` for the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` was never called to properly initialize things. The problem occurs only when the default value for the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` match the value of the view model property right from the start and the view model property is not changed. That's why I used this random default value.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the [`TextBox.CaretIndex` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex(v=vs.110).aspx) is *not* a `DependencyProperty`, so you cannot data bind to it. Even with your own `DependencyProperty`, it won't work... how would you expect to be notified when `TextBox.CaretIndex` Property changes?

Comment: i thought i could use some events to change the value

Comment: Sure, you can change the value, but you won't be notified when it changes on its own. However, you don't need a `DependencyProperty` just to change the value.

Comment: Ok i see, so how would you do try to get the `TextBox.CaretIndex` ?

Comment: @WiiMaxx, you can use behavior to store instance of `TextBox`, memorize current position, start timer and poll for changes (I am not sure how to pass changes to view-model and back). Also subscribe to `Unloaded` event to stop timer.

Comment: @Sheridan it would be nice if you could take a look at my answer maybe you are able to tell my whats wrong with my `BindsTwoWayByDefault = true`. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the [`FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions` Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [`FrameworkPropertyMetadata` Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557295(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @Sheridan sry for the late response, i tested your suggestion, but it has also no effect :( i used `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault`