# Load XAML at runtime, but control CLR-type resolving?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have a XAML-string describing a window, which contains a TextBox with a custom attached behavior:

```
<Window x:Class="System.Windows.Window" >
  <Grid>
    <TextBox behaviors:TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior.TrackCaretIndex="True"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to parse this at runtime, and instantiate the window it describes.
Currently, I'm doing:

```
    System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext = new System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext();
    parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add( "", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" );
    parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add( "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" );
    parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("behaviors", "clr-namespace:;assembly=" + typeof(TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior).Assembly.FullName);

    var window = (System.Windows.Window)XamlReader.Load(sr, parserContext);
    window.ShowDialog();
```

Which works in principle.
However, in my environment, I need to control how XAML tries to look up the corresponding CLR types when instantiating the window.

Specifically, the "TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior"-class in my assembly is actually named "Submission#0+TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior" in the compiled assembly, as it is created as part of a Roslyn script (see [WPF/XAML: How to reference class that is not defined within any namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786202/wpf-xaml-how-to-reference-class-that-is-not-defined-within-any-namespace) ).

Now "Submission#0+TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior" is an invalid format for a XAML file, so I can't use this directly in XAML.

The only way I can think of how to potentially solve my issue is if I could controle type resolving myself. I.e. when XamlReader (or any other class, if there are alternatives?) tries to find the CLR type corresponding to "behaviors:TextBoxCursorPositionBehavior", I would need to intercept that step and return the correct type.

Is there any way to do this?

So far, I have only found the XamlTypeMapper (passed via ParserContext), however seems like that one can only be used to control resolving namespaces.

Comment: did you try to overload [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve) and [`AppDomain.TypeResolve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve) to redirect to the correct assembly and type?

Comment: Great idea with TypeResolve, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in this case (it won't parse/load the XAML before even trying to resolve any types)