# How to get CaretIndex value of TextBox control in the view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Since `CaretIndex` of `TextBox` control is not a `DependencyProperty`, how do I get the value of `CaretIndex` in the ViewModel?

Comment: no, it 's not a duplicate

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233878/how-to-bind-to-caretindex-aka-curser-position-of-an-textbox)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Bind to CaretIndex aka curser position of an Textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233878/how-to-bind-to-caretindex-aka-curser-position-of-an-textbox)

Comment: You don't get the caret index in the view model.  View concerns don't belong in the view model.  If you're cramming them in there, then this isn't mvvm, and you can do it however you want, including adding codebehind to get the caret index, cast the datacontext to your view model, and change a property value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you `Interaction.Behaviors` create your own behaviour and get the property you want from it.

For eg. this is a `EventCommandConverterBehavior`. Using it will return the property value which you specify from `xaml`, and if property name is not set. it will return Corresponding `EventArgs`

```
public class EventCommandConverterBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    private Delegate eventHandler;
    private EventInfo oldEvent;

    // Event
    public string EventName { get { return (string)GetValue(EventNameProperty); } set { SetValue(EventNameProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EventName", typeof(string), typeof(EventCommandConverterBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnEventChanged));

    // Command
    public ICommand Command { get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); } set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventCommandConverterBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string PropertyName { get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyNameProperty); } set { SetValue(PropertyNameProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyName", typeof(string), typeof(EventCommandConverterBehavior), new PropertyMetadata());

    private static void OnEventChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var behavior = (EventCommandConverterBehavior)dependencyObject;

        if (behavior.AssociatedObject != null)
            behavior.AttachHandler((string)args.NewValue);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AttachHandler(this.EventName);
    }

    private void AttachHandler(string eventName)
    {
        // detach old event
        if (this.oldEvent != null)
            this.oldEvent.RemoveEventHandler(this.AssociatedObject, this.eventHandler);

        // attach new event
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventName))
        {
            return;
        }
        var eventInfo = this.AssociatedObject.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);
        if (eventInfo != null)
        {
            var methodInfo = this.GetType()
                .GetMethod("CommandExecuter", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            this.eventHandler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, this, methodInfo);
            eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this.AssociatedObject, this.eventHandler);
            this.oldEvent = eventInfo;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Type {0} does not contain event {1} definition.",
                this.AssociatedObject.GetType().Name, eventName));
    }

    private void CommandExecuter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object parameter = null != PropertyName ? GetPropValue(sender, PropertyName) : e;

        if (this.Command != null)
        {
            if (this.Command.CanExecute(parameter))
                this.Command.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }

    public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        var propertyInfo = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
        return propertyInfo != null ? propertyInfo.GetValue(src, null) : null;
    }
}
```

In `Xaml` you have to write

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="SomeText" Height="20" Width="60">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors >
        <wpfPractice:EventCommandConverterBehavior Command="{Binding PropertyValueCommand}" EventName="SelectionChanged" PropertyName="CaretIndex" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Where `PropertyValueCommand` shold be a command in DataContext(i.e. `ViewModel`.

let me know if it works.